# Reciprocal of measurable function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a measurable function and define
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{f(x)}, & f(x) \not= 0 \\
0, & f(x)=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $g(x)$ is also measurable.

Here's my reasoning so far: I have to show that the preimage $g^{-1}(S)$ of an open set $S$ is measurable. If we first assume that $S$ does not contain $0$, we get

$$g^{-1}(S) = \{x \mid g(x) \in S \} = \{x \mid \frac{1}{f(x)} \in S \} = \{x \mid f(x) \in S' \},$$
where $S' = \{\frac{1}{s} \mid s \in S\}$. Now since $f$ was measurable and $S'$ is an open set, the rightmost expression must be a measurable set. (I think you can also show that the composition of a measurable function and a continuous function is again measurable, that would be even shorter.)

I think I probably got that part right, but now I'm stuck on what to do if $0 \in S$. My first idea was that we could write $g^{-1}(S)$ as a union of two sets in the following way:

$$g^{-1}(S) = g^{-1}(S-\{0\}) \cup g^{-1}(0)$$

If this is a union of measurable sets, then it is measurable. But how do I know that $g^{-1}(0)=f^{-1}(0)$ is a measurable set? I know that the preimage of any *open* set is measurable, but the singleton $\{0\}$ isn't open, right?

Any **hints** would be appreciated, as would corrections to the above arguments.

Comment: Right, the singleton $\{0\}$ is not open. But do you know that the composition of a measurable function with a Borel function is again measurable?

Comment: Also, note that $$\{0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, I think I may have got it. By definition, a function is measurable if the inverse image of any *open* set is measurable. But actually I think this statement can be extended to say that the inverse image of any *Borel set* is measurable. If I can prove that, then the result follows since $\{0\}$ is a Borel set. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To prove it, prove that if $f\colon X \to Y$ is any map, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, then $\mathcal{F} = \{ B \subset Y : f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.