# Suppose $f$ is a measurable function, $\mathbb{A}$ a sigma-algebra of set. then $\frac{1}{f}$ is a measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is a measurable function, $\mathbb{A}$ a sigma-algebra of set. then $\frac{1}{f}$ is a measurable function.

**My attempt:**
Suppose $c>0$
$$(\frac{1}{f})^{-1}((\ c,\infty\ ))=\{x:\frac{1}{f(x)}>c\}=\{x:\frac{1}c>f(x)\}$$

Here, i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/961392/9464

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, what is your definition of $\frac{1}{f}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: your set is $f^{-1}(\cdots)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to assume that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. It is not enough to consider $c>0$. Write $\{x:\frac 1 {f(x)} >c\}$ as $f^{-1}(0,\frac 1 c)$ when $c >0$. Now let $c <0$. Then you get $f^{-1}((0,\infty) \cup (-\infty, \frac 1 c))$. What happens if $c=0$?